# Given an positive integer array, rearrange the array so that the sum of product of adjacent elements can be maximized

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Interview question. I am looking for an algorithm that can do better than O(n^2), where n is the size of the input array. (n<5000)

The questions states as follows:

Assume we are given an array of positive integer (let's call it a). Find out a way to re-arrange the order of these element so that the value of the following function can be maximized:

**obj = a[0]*a[1] + a[1]*a[2] + ... + a[n-2]*a[n-1] + a[n-1]*a[n]**

In addition, there is also an array of boolean (let's call it b), which has the exactly same size as the positive integer array. If b[k] = false, it means that when we re-arrange the element in the positive array, we cannot move the kth elements.

---

**Example**

a = [ 1,2,3 ], b = [ true, true, true ]

Since all elements of b is true, we can re-arrange array a whatever we know. There are six ways to re-array it (e.g. [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3] ....). The following are the objective function value for these six arrangement. The arrangement that maximize the objective function is [1,3,2] or [2,3,1] since:

1 * 3 + 3 * 2 = 9

2 * 3 + 3 * 1 = 9

Another example:

a = [ 1,2,3 ],  b = [ true, false, true ]

In this case, integer 2 cannot be moved so there are only two arrangement - [1,2,3] and [3,2,1]. Both of them yield the same objective function value.

---

**Update**

I used brute force method to test the algorithm provided by @shapiro.yaacov on positive integer array with distinct elements. Here is some test I run:

input: [ 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 ]

output:

obj = 3412, when [2, 8, 32, 64, 16, 4, 1] or

obj = 3412, when [1, 4, 16, 64, 32, 8, 2]

input: [1, 10, 100, 1000]

output:

obj = 110100, when [1, 100, 1000, 10] or

obj = 110100, when [10, 1000, 100, 1]

As you can see, there are at least two arrangements that can maximize the objective function - one arrange is the reversed version of the another one.

Even this is not the requirement of this question, this algorithm works with those array with 0 too. However, we need to come up with the best arrangement without the zero, and then append 0 to either side of the new arrangement. For example:

input: [0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64]

output:

obj = 3412, when [2, 8, 32, 64, 16, 4, 1, 0] or

obj = 3412, when [0, 2, 8, 32, 64, 16, 4, 1] or

obj = 3412, when [1, 4, 16, 64, 32, 8, 2, 0] or

obj = 3412, when [0, 1, 4, 16, 64, 32, 8, 2]

Comment: Whats the maximum range of `n`?

Comment: What's your `O(n^2)` algorithm for doing it?

Comment: I'm thinking that you can look for swaps that increase the value of obj, and stop when there are no more such swaps. Normally that gives only a local max, not a global max, but the special form of the function could mean that there's only one local max = global max. Swapping is part of sorting so that could mean there's an O(n log n) solution ...

Comment: I was told the n will be less than 5000 during the interview. @KaidulIslam I didn't have a O(n^2) but I was asked to provide a solution better than that.

Comment: Since `n < 5000` is guaranteed, why don't you just pad the array with 0s until you have an array of length 5000. Then brute force, it will be `O(1)` by default.

Comment: @k_g I don't think I get what you are saying. In my understanding, brute force mean that (1) you need to get all permutation from the given array (e.g. if the given array is {1,2,3} then its has 6 permutation [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1] ) (2) calculate the objective function for all permutation and find the maximal one. If n = 12, there are more than 1 million permutation so the brute force method does not work.

Comment: @JZhang that was meant more as a throwaway than anything else. If you know the maximum bound on `n`, technically big O notation is useless since it deals with behavior near infinity.

Basically, if you force `len = 5000` in all cases, you end up with `5000! = O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with `O(n*logn)`:

Take array `a`, and sort all the (possible) elements in it. By possible I mean those who's index in the b array is true. This step takes `O(n*logn)`.

**Deprecated:**
Given the **obj** function, you want to multiply the biggest number with the second biggest, the second with the third etc. Some optimization might be done here by swapping `a[0]` with the smallest number and then a[1] would be the biggest etc. (with `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]` **obj** is bigger). In any case, since you have the array sorted already, this step is an easy `O(n)`.

**Edit:**
Given the **obj** function, and after a conversation with @Edward Doolittle, this is probably the best arrangement:

```
[1, ..., n-4, n-2, n, n-1, n-3, ...., 2]
```

**Edit 2:**

Dealing with the elements that can not be moved: start with sorting the elements you *can* sort. Then look at the locations where they can go and sort the locations by the multipliers on both sides. So if an optional location has 8 on one side and 3 on the other, it multiplier's value is 24. Then assign the highest value element to the highest value location.

Can't prove right now that this is optimal, but it isn't THAT far off. I think.

Comment: The largest element should go in the middle of the array, not the end, so that both the second and third largest can multiply by it, no? Then do we want the fourth largest multiplying the second largest or the third largest?

Comment: I am contemplating that exactly. Ideally, I'd like to multiply the top three numbers in pairs. Since this is impossible, n*(n-1) and n*(n-2) will do. Then also do (n-1)*(n-3) and (n-2)*(n-4). This leads me to think of what you said:  1, ..., n-4, n-2, n, n-1, n-3, ...., 2

Comment: Thanks! Your algorithm runs at O(n*logn) if the positive integer array is unsorted and there is no constrains on their position. How would you fit this method if the position constrains is added?